# How to add custom counter to Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

I defined a custom counter for writing research questions in my paper:

```
\newcounter{researchquestionCount}
\newcommand{\researchquestion}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{researchquestionCount}\vspace{18pt}
    \noindent {\large \textbf{RQ\,\arabic{researchquestionCount}\; \emph{#1}}} \vspace{8pt}
}
```

And it successfully generates headings. For example, by writing

```
\researchquestion{This is the first}

This is normal text below the heading, describing it

\researchquestion{This is the second}

This is normal text below the heading, describing it
```

I get something like:

---

**RQ1 *This is the first***

This is normal text below the heading, describing it

**RQ2 *This is the second***

This is normal text below the heading, describing it

---

Now, I want to include all of the RQs in my TOC. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that you need is `\addcontentsline`:

[image]

It could be better if you the OP gave a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). As it didn't, here is one possible hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\parindent=0pt

\newcounter{researchquestionCount}
\renewcommand\theresearchquestionCount{\textbf{RQ\arabic{researchquestionCount}}}
\newcommand{\researchquestion}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{researchquestionCount}\vspace{18pt}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\theresearchquestionCount\space#1}%
  \noindent{\large\theresearchquestionCount\space\emph{#1}}\newline\vspace{8pt}%
}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \researchquestion{This is the first}

  This is normal text below the heading, describing it

  \researchquestion{This is the second}

  This is normal text below the heading, describing it

\end{document}
```

Note that I have defined and used `\theresearchquestionCount`. Rather than this approach, I would define `\researchquestion` using `\trivlist`:

```
\newcommand{\researchquestion}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{researchquestionCount}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\theresearchquestionCount\space#1}\vspace{8pt}%
  \trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\textbf{\large\theresearchquestionCount}\space]%
    \ignorespaces\emph{#1}\vspace{8pt}%
}
```

Mind you, the output is much the same as before...